# Limit of complex function if z doesn't approach zero

Tags: complex-analysis

$\lim_{z\to 3+i}Im(z) = Im(3+i) = 1$

I'm not sure if that works because I'm not sure if I actually covered all directions or not. How would I properly calculate this limit?

Comment: "How would I properly calculate this limit?" By using the definition of $\lim$. An $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof will always be proper. And this problem is simple enough that it's not really that cumbersome.

Comment: @xotix Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I'll choose one, I just was very busy. But thanks for remining.

Comment: @xotix Sorry if I remeber that fact but I see that many people here ask for helping and they do not even select an answer nor say thanks for the effort and time spent to help them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$ shuch that for

$$|z-z_0|=|x-3+i(y-1)|=\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-1)^2}<\delta$$
$$\implies|\Im(z)-1|<\epsilon\iff|y-1|<\epsilon$$

then it suffices to take $\delta\le\epsilon$ such that the open ball $|z-z_0|<\delta$ is contained in the horizontal strip $|y-1|<\epsilon$.

Comment: ok thanks, so in such a situation one would always go with the definition? Are there other tools?

Comment: Yes note that the following theorem holds $$\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = z_0 = u_0+iv_0 \iff \lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} u(x,y) = u_0 \,\land \,  \lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} v(x,y) = v_0$$